# how to get additional fields on udemy api

Tags: api

I would like to list fields on course eg title,header when use course-list. does anybody knows about a way to query by fields so the returned list of fields ?

when query on

```
GET api-2.0/courses/?category=Development&subcategory=Web Development&price=price-free&is_affiliate_agreed=True&instructional_level=all&fields=title,headline
```

result 
[image]

result is count all query